# MAUI (blazor) appicon issue on windows taskbar and on android

Tags: maui, maui-blazor

I have a lot of problems to display correcty a normal very simple appicon (both png or svg) on windows or android

1. On Win11 Taskbar the content of my pic is very tiny and with a "red" frame around it (red comes from the active theme, if you change theme, color could changes).
2. On Android the content of my pic is "zoomed" and I see only the central part of the icon

I tried dozens or more of combinations with bitmap, vector, only one file, with composite files (icon + foreground), with BaseSize, ForegroundScale Factor, Color & Tint, etc.

I used one day to write the app and I'm here since 2 days only for the icon!! Crazy!

Suppose I want my logo (here a 256x256 png with the corner transparent) as Icon

Why I can't have a circle big like Chrome or Edge?
And why Android make a zoom and cut the outer part?

Thx

[image: Logo png 256x256]

[image: Win11 taskbar]

[image: Android]

Comment: You can check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/app-icons?tabs=android#use-a-different-icon-per-platform).

Comment: Already done and following what they say, I have those results

Comment: Could you provide some relevant code, so that I can reproduce the situation you described.

Comment: there isn't any code... create a blank project, save the png of my logo (or take another png), copy in the /resources/appicon folder (deleting the two existing svg), mark with Build action "MauiIcon" and try the 2 deployments.

Comment: I tested, and as you said: the size is not what you want. This is [mine](https://imgur.com/a/c6tWWXm). So, have you tried to change the size of image(your logo) to adapt platform.